# Can NJ's rebate program for electric vehicles be resumed just by the governor's direction?

Tags: car, new-jersey

NJ has a program which provides a substantial rebate on the purchase or lease of an electric vehicle. In addition, NJ doesn't charge sales tax on EV. Couple that with the federal rebate and EVs are potentially affordable for us.

I had [learned that NJ had paused the program](https://chargeup.njcleanenergy.com/) effective November 21st of 2023 due to the relevant funds being depleted and thus unavailable. But the program had been [paused before on April 2023](https://www.nj.gov/bpu/newsroom/2023/approved/20230417.html) and I wasn't even aware that the program at some point restarted.

Can someone advise me on what's necessary for the program to restart? Does it require the passage of legislation by the State Assembly? Or can the governor just authorize the disbursement of already allocated funds?

I ask because I think the former might be less likely to occur than the latter and I'm trying to figure out how to time the purchase of an EV with consideration for these things. Right now I'm looking and due to the lack of the NJ rebate, a car I'm looking at has a lease payment that's $70 a month higher than if it had the rebate; so if it's just a matter of wait until February or March for the governor to reauthorize the program then that's what I'll do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about interpretation of State law, not personal finance.

Comment: How that law gets handled relates to how I would handle my personal finances on this. If somebody can advise me on how the program is administered, I can make a more informed decision. I'm not asking if this program is definitely coming back, I'm only asking how does it get it's approval, because when it exists it makes this personal expenditure much more affordable.

Comment: Additionally, there are plenty of questions on here asking for interpretation of federal laws that affect folks' personal finance. So I'm not sure why this isn't acceptable.

Comment: We're usually discussing interpretation of tax laws as they pertain to individuals, not limits of executive authority under the state law. Maybe rephrase the question a bit, but even then you're asking for speculation about the future - even if the governor can legally reauthorize it, there's no guarantee that he would.